# ROR: Updating two models from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models profiles and users on my form. After a user is created he can then move to editing his profile. The views work well. But when I click Save to update the editted profile. It doesn't update, but the flash notice displays that profile has been updated. What might be wrong? I'm not sure what went wrong. Below is the code.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    #@user.profile = Profile.new
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @identity = @user.profile || @user.build_profile()
    @identity.save
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    @identity = @user.profile
    if @identity.update_attributes(params[:identity])
      flash[:notice] = 'Profile was successfully updated.'
      redirect_to(new_profile_path())
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end


class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @identity = @user.profile || @user.build_profile()
    @identity.save
  end

......

end
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Check your development.log and see what params are being passed in - perhaps you're not sending anything through in params[:identity]

Comment: Just a heads up, you can simply this line: `@identity = @user.profile || @user.build_profile()` into this: `@user.profile ||= Profile.new`.

Comment: @Cory.. I checked the log it seems to sure a success with the up but items don't still get updated.

Comment: @ryeguy...I get an error when I use @user.profile ||= Profile.new

Comment: @Cory.. its seems nothing is going into params[identity]. how do I correct this?

Comment: That's hard to say! Just have a look at the form you're using to submit to this action and ensure that it's scoped to :identity...

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially a few things wrong here.  But the best solution to this problem would be to simplify and use the built in rails features for editing associations.

What I suggest doing is using nested attributes, [Ryan Daigle has a great article on them](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes).

I'm not sure why you're calling `save` in a `new` action and not in a `create`, that doesn't feel right.  Also check that the name of the model in the form you're submitting is `identity` and not `user` or `profile`.

Can a user exist without a profile?

Comment: Thanks for the reply jonnii. A user can not exist without a profile. A user has one profile and a profile belongs to one user.

Comment: I would add a callback on user to create the profile when the user is created, it'll simplify your code.

Comment: @jonnii..how do I do that? Can you show me with a code sample?